# Passing gulp-front-matter value to gulp-wrap

Tags: gulp

I'm hoping to do something like this:

```
gulp.src('src/*.html')
  .pipe(fm ({
    property: 'fm'
  }))
  .pipe(wrap({
    src: fm['template']
  }))
```

where `template` is a value in the front-matter. I can create a separate function where I pass the value using gulp-tap but I was hoping to keep it 
"simple". I don't think `gulp-wrap` supports accessing front-matter vars.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be one solution but it starts to fail as I add more complexity, for instance with gulp-swig.

The source file contains:

```
---
template: full
---

Text content is here.
```

and the script:

```
var frontMatter   = require('gulp-front-matter'),
    gulp          = require('gulp'),
    tap           = require('gulp-tap'),
    wrap          = require('gulp-wrap')

gulp.task('default', function() {
  gulp.src('src/*.html')
    .pipe(frontMatter())
    .pipe(tap(function(file) {
      gulp.src(file.path)
        .pipe(frontMatter ({
          remove: true
        }))
        .pipe(wrap({
          src: file.frontMatter['template'] + '.tpl' // ==> full.tpl
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'))
    }))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a function as the first argument of `gulp-wrap`.

The document of `gulp-wrap` says

> When a Function then the function will be called and should return the
>   template content. This function get the data object as first
>   parameter.

Something like the following should work.

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
var fm = require('gulp-front-matter')
var wrap = require('gulp-wrap')

var fs = require('fs')

gulp.src('src/*.html')
  .pipe(fm({property: 'fm'}))
  .pipe(wrap(function (data) {
    return fs.readFileSync('path/to/layout_dir/' + data.file.fm.template + '.tpl').toString()
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'))
```

See also:
[Gulp Front Matter +Markdown through Nunjucks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32810072/gulp-front-matter-markdown-through-nunjucks/34625967#34625967)