# A gulp workflow with markdown and nunjucks

Tags: gulp, markdown, nunjucks

I am working on setting up a workflow for generating static pages using Markdown and Nunjucks, through Gulp. The current two tasks I rely on for this are:

```
gulp.task('templates', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/templates/pages/*.nunjucks') 
        .pipe(nunjucksRender({
        path: ['app/templates/', 'app/templates/pages/']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app'));
});

gulp.task('pages', function() {
    gulp.src('app/pages/**/*.md')
        .pipe(frontMatter())
        .pipe(marked())
        .pipe(wrap(function (data) {
            return fs.readFileSync('app/templates/pages/' + data.file.frontMatter.layout).toString()
        }, null, {engine: 'nunjucks'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app'))
});
```

With the following structure:

```
/app
|   index.html
|
+---css
|       app.scss
|       custom.scss
|
+---js
|       app.js
|
+---pages
|       index.md
|
\---templates
    |   layout.nunjucks
    |
    +---macros
    |       nav-macro.nunjucks
    |
    +---pages
    |       index.nunjucks
    |
    \---partials
            navigation.nunjucks
```

If I run `gulp templates` this compiles index.html into /app using index.nunjucks which extends layout.nunjucks. However, I want to use `gulp pages` to draw frontmatter and Markdown from index.md to generate the contents of index.html.

The problem I am having is pathing: Given the structure above, how to I use /app/pages/index.md as the content for /app/index.html through /app/templates/pages/index.nunjucks? Currently the task fails with `Template render error: (unknown path)`.

Essentially, I am trying to extend what is achieved here: [Gulp Front Matter +Markdown through Nunjucks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32810072/gulp-front-matter-markdown-through-nunjucks/34625967#34625967)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have a simplified version of your setup running that uses the exact same Gulpfile.js you posted. It looks like this:

```
project/Gulpfile.js 
project/index.html 
project/app/pages/index.md
project/app/templates/layout.nunjucks
project/app/templates/pages/index.nunjucks
```

**index.md**

```
---
title: Example
layout: index.nunjucks
date: 2016-03-01
---
This is the text
```

**layout.nunjucks**

```
<h1>{{file.frontMatter.title}}</h1>

<div class="date">{% block date %}{% endblock %}</div>

<div>{% block text %}{% endblock %}</div>
```

**index.nunjucks**

```
{% extends "app/templates/layout.nunjucks" %}

{% block date %}
{{file.frontMatter.date}}
{% endblock %}

{% block text %}
{{contents}}
{% endblock %}
```

**index.html** after running `gulp pages`:

```
<h1>Example</h1>

<div class="date">
Tue Mar 01 2016 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
</div>

<div>
<p>This is the text</p>

</div>
```

The tricky part that you're probably getting wrong is how to specify the path for `{% extends %}` in **index.nunjucks** or some other place.

When you run gulp it changes the current working directory (CWD) to the folder where the Gulpfile.js is located (in my case: **project/**). By default nunjuck uses a [`FileSystemLoader`](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html#filesystemloader) that searches the CWD to load other templates. That means all the paths in your **.nunjucks** files need to be relative to the CWD, i.e. your project's base folder.

Theoretically it should be possible to provide your own `FileSystemLoader` so you can specify template paths relative to **index.nunjucks**, but `gulp-wrap` uses [`consolidate`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/consolidate) internally to abstract away the differences between the many templating engines and I haven't bothered to figure out how and if that allows you to provide a custom loader.

Comment: That was indeed the problem, and in thinking about it pathing relative to the working directory is preferable because path-juggling is then not necessary. Thanks for a thorough and well-explained answer.